# Adobe CQ JCR query caching

Tags: java, aem

I am new to StackOverflow, and I have a question about Querying in CQ jcr. I wonder is there a way to cache the query result.

For example. I want to query some nodes that in most cases will not change often, and I am using an QueryManager to build the query, and I want to know is there a way to cache those result.

Comment: This might give some idea http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1071973

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of caching the query result, you would have to implement your own application level solution.
When implementing this, cache the actual data you want to display to the user instead of caching the node results.  This will be far more efficient and will help you avoid retaining extra objects in memory.

In addition to creating your own result cache, there is a cacheSize setting which you can configure in the SearchIndex element of crx-quickstart/repository/workspaces/crx.default/workspace.xml.  This setting is available in CQ5.6.1 and earlier (not in AEM6.0).  It maps node uuids to lucene document numbers.

Here's the related documentation on this feature:
http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/Search#Search-1